# Issue with data-th-id

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I have a button that leads to a modal view. I try to intercept the value with JS.

**It works like this:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-person-id="something">
  Edit
</button>
```

**JaveScript**:

```
var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('person-id');
```

**It doesn't work like this:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#myModal" data-th-id="${person.getId()}">
  Edit
</button>
```

JS:

```
var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
```

or

```
var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('th-id');
```

var is undefined it says.

Since I use Thymeleaf I need to catch the value with data-th-id.

Any idea how to get the value

Complete JS

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#myInput').focus();
    var bookId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    alert(e.relatedTarget.nodeName);
    alert(bookId);
});
```

Comment: Have you inspected the HTML in dev console and confirmed that there indeed some value assigned to that `data-th-id` attribute?

Comment: yes it shows that line: <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#myModal" id="113">
So it contains id with 113

Comment: can you show the full js? Is the event listener on the button? In that case you probably want to use `this` or maybe `e.target`? Hard to say without the code.

Comment: Sure I added it to the bottom of my question

Comment: can you log `e.relatedTarget` to make sure it is the button?

Comment: oh i see you are kind of doing that already. Does that `alert` show you the button as expected?

Comment: yes the first alert displays "BUTTON"

Comment: Could you try `.data(thId)`

Comment: May not help, but can you change `person.getId()` to `person.id`?

Comment: Try using `e.relatedTarget.dataset['url']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery retrieve relatedTarget.data('url') value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173242/jquery-retrieve-relatedtarget-dataurl-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-person-id="something"` is a data attribute, and is accessed with `$('...').data('person-id')`.

`data-th-id="${person.getId()}"` isn't a data attribute.  It's just a different way of saying `th:id`, which outputs the `id="..."` attribute of a tag.  You can't use jQuery's `.data()` method on non-data attributes, instead you use `attr()` -- `$(e.relatedTarget).attr('id');`